# Find documents where value occurs in array

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to find each Community where a user occurs in its members array.

I'm using Mongoose and I'm not sure how to structure my .find();

My Community schema looks like this:

```
var communitySchema = mongoose.Schema({
name         : String,
author       : String,
created_on   : Date,
members      : Array,
posts        : Array
});
```

My current attempts:

```
var cquery = Community.find({ members : { "$in" : [current_user]}});
var cquery = Community.find({ members : 'current_user'});
```

Comment: That looks like it should work. Are you getting an error or something?

Comment: Which one is the correct one? Yeah, it returns nothing.

Comment: Both look correct. Are you sure that the `current_user` really is in the members array? I also noticed that in one case `current_user` is a variable, in the other its a string.

Comment: I was assigning the wrong value to current_user and that's what was causing the error. Thanks for that. I derped.